# Адаптивная высота блока для вертикальных блоков

Tags: css, html, height

Есть родительский блок `item`, внутри него еще 2 блока: `item_info` и `item_img`
Как сделать так чтобы блок `item` адаптировался по высоте относительно двух его дочерних блоков? (`item` имеет свойство border-bottom - серую линию снизу. Как сделать так, чтобы эта линия оказалась под блоком?) Заранее спасибо <3 
https://jsfiddle.net/birdthelittle/5ofgf8ay/

Comment: Почитай про float побольше, там есть нюансы

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение через `flex-box`. Убрал все `float` и заменил на `display:flex;`
Подробнее [тут](http://html5.by/blog/flexbox/)